# Tkinter window open behind only window running in mainloop

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I would like only the "menu" window to be running at the beginning of the program and the "board" window to open when the "PLAY!" button is pressed however the window is already there when the program starts and pressing the play button just packs all of the features inside of the function.

```
from Tkinter import *
menuw = Tk()
boardw = Tk()
menuw.title("menu")
menuw.configure(bg="ivory")
boardw.title("Treasure Hunt!")
boardw.configure(bg="ivory")

rows = 8 #sets the number of rows in the grid
columns = 8 # sets the number of columns in the grid
size = 75 #sets the size of each square
colour1 = "white" #sets the colour of half of the squares
colour2 = "black" #sets the colour of the other half of the squares
canvas_width = columns * size 
canvas_height = rows * size 

def Board():
    rows = 8 
    columns = 8 
    size = 50 
    colour1 = "white" 
    colour2 = "black" 
    canvas_width = columns * size 
    canvas_height = rows * size 
    Frame(boardw)
    global canvas
    canvas = Canvas(boardw, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, background="ivory")
    canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True, padx=2, pady=2)
    canvas.bind("<Configure>", refresh)
    canvas1 = Canvas(boardw, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, width=canvas_width, height=20, background="ivory")
    canvas1.pack(side = "bottom", fill= "both", expand = True, padx=4, pady=4)
    gold = 0 
    score = Label(boardw, text = ("score = {0}").format(gold), bg="ivory", font = "haettenschweiler 15")
    score.pack()
    treasurechests = 10
    tcn = Label(boardw, text = ("Number of treasure chests remaining = {0}").format(treasurechests), bg="ivory", font = "haettenschweiler 15")
    tcn.pack()
    bandits = 5
    bn = Label(boardw, text = ("Number of bandits chests remaining = {0}").format(bandits), bg="ivory", font = "haettenschweiler 15")
    bn.pack()
    playerpos = [0,0]
    pos = Label(boardw, text = ("position = {0}").format(playerpos), bg="ivory", font = "haettenschweiler 15")
    pos.pack()

def refresh(event):
    xsize = int((event.width-1) / columns)
    ysize = int((event.height-1) / rows)
    size = min(xsize, ysize)
    canvas.delete("square")
    colour = colour2
    for row in range(rows):
        colour = colour1 if colour == colour2 else colour2
        for col in range(columns):
            x1 = (col * size)
            y1 = (row * size)
            x2 = x1 + size
            y2 = y1 + size
            canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="black", fill=colour, tags="square")
            colour = colour1 if colour == colour2 else colour2
    canvas.tag_raise("piece")
    canvas.tag_lower("square")
    canvas.pack(side = "top", fill= "both", expand = True, padx=4,pady=4)

def menu():
    titlel = Label(menuw, text = "Treasure Hunt!", font = "Haettenschweiler 50", fg = "black", bg= "ivory")
    titlel.pack()
    playb = Button(menuw, text = "PLAY", font = "Haettenschweiler 15", fg = "black", bg= "ivory", command = Board)
    playb.pack()
    quitb = Button(menuw, text = "QUIT", font = "Haettenschweiler 15", fg = "black", bg= "ivory", command = menuw.destroy)
    quitb.pack()

menu()
menuw.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are creating two instances of Tkinter:

```
menuw = Tk()
boardw = Tk()
```

In almost all cases, you won't want to do this, instead, to create a new window, use `Toplevel()` for your board, and allow `menuw` to be the root window:

```
from Tkinter import *
menuw = Tk()
menuw.title("menu")
menuw.configure(bg="ivory")

....

def Board():
    boardw = Toplevel()
    boardw.title("Treasure Hunt!")
    boardw.configure(bg="ivory")
    ....
```

Also this line: `Frame(boardw)` isn't doing anything, since you never sent it to a layout manager (pack, place, grid) to have it displayed.